# How to make a product of function in Scala

Tags: scala, function

I've got an exercise to create a product of two functions from the code below:

```
 def prod[A, B, C, D](f: A => C, g: B => D): (A, B) => (C, D) = {
    
  }
```

My plan was to do something like this, but it doesn't work, because it can't resolve symbols A and B.

```
def prod[A, B, C, D](f: A => C, g: B => D): (A, B) => (C, D) = {
        v1: (A,B) => f(A)*g(B)
      }
```

Comment: The problem isn't the symbols `A, B` the problem is `*` which doesn't work for arbitrary types and is not needed in this case; you just want to return a tuple. Also `f(A)` doesn't work you need to access the elements of the tuples.-

Comment: if I do v1: (A,B) => (f(A), g(B)) it says that it can't resolve symbols A and B :/

Comment: Yes because `A` is a type, not a value, you need to access the value inside the tuple. Check the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Tuple2.html) or check how to use [**pattern matching**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html).

Comment: Thank you and I'm sorry, but I'm beginner in Scala.
I made this:  v1: (A,B) => (f(v1._1), g(v1._2))
Now it says that "Missing parameter B" - isn't g(v1._2) the B parameter?

Comment: @squall the error is misleading, if you see [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/8ubB8GiFTf2fGpRO01jx5A/1) you will see that the error is a bit clearer. The problem is that your code returns a **function** of a single argument and such argument is a **tuple**, whereas you say you will return a **function** from two arguments. You can do this to return a function of two arguments: `def prod[A, B, C, D](f: A => C, g: B => D): (A, B) => (C, D) = (a, b) => (f(a), g(b))`

Comment: you are right- it works now. I have a question why can't I specify additionally in .... (a,b): (A,B)?  (it gives an error)

Comment: @squall if you really want to add those type annotations you need to do it one parameter at the time, like methods: thus `(a: A, b: B) =>` but they are inferred by the compiler and I personally believe that is just extra verbosity, the method clearly states that it will return a function of two arguments `A & B`

Comment: of course it works, but I just wanted to know additonally how to do it :) thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome :) - anyways, the question was very simple and will probably be closed as caused by a typo, so I will suggest you to delete it manually before that. Also, if you have more questions like this maybe a chat channel like [**gitter**](https://gitter.im/scala/scala) would be better.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax to define a function type signature and a function definition is different. When you return a value, you need to return the function definition.

```
def prod[A, B, C, D](f: A => C, g: B => D): (A, B) => (C, D) = 
  (a: A, b: B) => (f(a), g(b))
```